# Seaborn diagonal correlation matrix skip first row and last column

Tags: python, seaborn

How can I drop the label and corresponding column/row (the white space) from  the following plot? In this particular case in would correspond to row ***a*** and column ***l***.

```
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)

corr = scaled_df.select_dtypes(include = ['float64', 'int64']).corr()

sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap='inferno', vmin = -0.1, vmax=0.8, square=True)
plt.axvline(1.0, color='white', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 2.5, alpha = 1.0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two fairly easy ways to approach this:

A. pass the valid /desired subset of data to the plotter

```
corr = np.random.rand(10,10)
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

sns.heatmap(corr[1:,:-1], mask=mask[1:,:-1], cmap='inferno', vmin = -0.1, vmax=0.8, square=True)
```

B. after rendering, adjust the limits of the plot

```
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap='inferno', vmin = -0.1, vmax=0.8, square=True)
ax.set_xlim(0,9)
ax.set_ylim(10,1)
```

It isn't clear whether you always have have triangular valid regions, but you could detect the limits of
your matrices from the mask according to the rows that are all set in the mask and equivalently for the 
columns.  But for valid regions deriving from triu (or tril) the limits are just 1 fron the start / end.

Comment: Thank you, of course, the second answer should have been super obvious to me!